# C - Socket Chat Room - Client Receive Consecutive Messages

Tags: c, sockets

I'm working on a client(s)/server command line chat program in C using sockets.  I've gotten everything working pretty well except one issue.  When the client submits an invalid command to the server I'm trying to send back the list of commands to inform them how to use the application.  I was trying to do this by performing multiple successive "send"s, but the client only gets the first message.  I found several similar questions (mostly for Java sockets), but no answer that helped me figure this out.

Code and Output

Server Side Code:

```
void message_self(char *msg, client_t *client) {
    send(client->sd, msg, strlen(msg) + 1, 0);
}

void commands(client_t *client) {
    message_self("Commands:\n", client);
    message_self("\tUser Login:\tlogin <username> <password\n", client);
    message_self("\tCreate User:\tnewuser <username> <password>\n", client);
    message_self("\tList Users:\twho\n", client);
    message_self("\tMessaging:\tsend all|<username> <message>\n", client);
    message_self("\tQuit Chat:\tlogout\n", client);
}
```

Client Side (in a separate thread loop):

```
if((len = recv(sd, buff_in, sizeof(buff_in), 0)) > 0) {
    fputs(buff_in, stdout);
}
```

Output: The blank line is the user just hitting enter so server would call commands(client).  After only receiving 1 line, user input "send" and got the corresponding error message from the server.

```
Connected. Chat Room Version 2

Commands:
send
Server: Denied. Please log in.
```

If I put usleep(50) between each message_self then I get the expected output:

```
Connected. Chat Room Version 2

Commands:
    User Login:     login <username> <password>
    Create User:    newuser <username> <password>
    List Users:     who
    Messaging:      send all|<username> <message>
    Quit Chat:      logout
```

I just figured there must be a better way.  I also tried concatenating the entire list into one buffer with all formatting characters, but it still cut off on client side after just printing "Commands:".  If anyone has any idea how to fix this either from client side of server side, I'd be grateful.

Comment: When sending, you include the terminating `'\0'` after each line. On the receiving side, `fputs` only prints until the first `'\0'`, i.e. only one line. The reason why all lines are sent in one packet is probably [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm). Usually one should not rely on the null-termination of data received over network, and instead send the length of the data to follow first.

Comment: If your buffers are large enough, you could consider sending the whole command list in one message.

Comment: @KarstenKoop - this makes sense, then i can easily break it apart on client side.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - magically this works now, despite it not working when i tried before.  perhaps simply how i was building the string the first time i tried it.

Answer (score 0):

As @KarstenKoop commented, sending the null terminator from the server screws everything up.  Instead, just send strlen bytes and use len on the client side to terminate the message for fputs.

Server:

```
send(client->sd, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
```

Client:

```
if((len = recv(sd, buff_in, sizeof(buff_in), 0)) > 0) {
    buff_in[len] = '\0';
    fputs(buff_in, stdout);
}
```